# Lightbox not working when including lightbox.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm trying to implement an image gallery using Lightbox. Using the example everything works fine. Since I'm using Bootstrap and already linking to JQuery I'd like use `lightbox.js` instead of `lightroom-plus-jquery.js`. This, however, breaks the functionality and all images are opened fullscreen like regular links.

On the official website I couldn't find any information and no other example code is provided. So I hope someone here can help me fix it.

This is a minimal html based on the example:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Lightbox Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <div>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors which you can debug when using `lightbox.js`

Comment: I forgot to mention there are no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with `jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js` Please Use `jquery.min.js`.

Example is Here : https://codepen.io/mrdvpatel/pen/BgVpZQ

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
*{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.example-image-link img {
    width: 24%;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Lightbox Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.0/css/lightbox.css">
</head>
<body>
<section class="images">
 <a class="example-image-link" href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt=""/></a>
 <a class="example-image-link" href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0000/fff" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0000/fff" alt="" /></a>
 <a class="example-image-link" href="https://dummyimage.com/400x600/000/fff" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x600/000/fff" alt="" /></a>
 <a class="example-image-link" href="https://dummyimage.com/400x600/ff0000/fff" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x600/ff0000/fff" alt="" /></a>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.0/js/lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
   <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Lightbox Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.0/css/lightbox.css">
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <div>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.0/js/lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you